# fstream behaving weirdly

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, ofstream

I am new to c++, but this is ridiculous!

```
// fstream output;
// string func();

// both have proven to be working somewhat properly, as I got something already
// written correctly in the output file and I tested func() in the cout

output << func(); // func() returns a string;
```

And I get written in the file:

```
// literally nothing
```

But when I do

```
output << "what the hell" << endl;
output << func();
```

I get

```
what the hell
{// expected output}
what the hell
{// expected output}
...
what the hell
// last output still missing
```

I got no idea of what might be the problem, at this point I am convinced the program is just doing it to spite me.

EDIT:

```
string func()
{
    return "test\n";
}
```

I also just found out that as long as I manually put something to the output in the end, everything will be written, like this:

```
for(int=0; i<4; i++)
{
    output << func();
}
output << endl;
```

get me

```
test
test
test
test
// func line
// endl line
```

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Smells like undefined behaviour in `func`

Comment: Please post a full [MCVE]. What is the actual code in `func()`?

Comment: Umm, are you sure the text editor you use is doing a refresh on file change? maybe try output << func() << std::endl; to force a flush.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using an old version of mingw which fails to flush cout on exit

Comment: Post real code. And note that formally, the end of an output stream must have a newline character. That's usually not an issue, but it's impossible to say from the various random code snippets in the question.

Comment: @PeteBecker is that a requirement of the language or just that posix utilities expect text files to end with a new line?

Comment: @AlanBirtles -- I'm away from my references right now, but my recollection is that it's a library requirement. Seems to me that it had something to do with record-oriented OSes on IBM mainframes that required heroic efforts to implement text streams.

Answer (score 0):

As  One Man Monkey Squad commented, it was just a problem of not flushing the fstream.

```
string func()
{
   return "test"
}

output << func() << endl;
```

get me the desired output, without a extra line at the end, beyond the normal new line